# substituting transistors and diodes

Tags: substitution

I'm a new hobbyist, I need a tip 121 transistor and a 2N4148 diode. I'm using the site taydaelectronics.com. This site doesn't have these items. A friend tells me that there parts can probably be substituted for others. Can someone help me figure out what parts I can use in their place?

Tip 121

2N4148 diode

Thank you

edit:

Here is the schematic I'm working from.

[image: here is the image]

Comment: Your diode is a **1**N4148 and it depends on how & where you're using them.

Comment: Look at the ratings of the transistor and diodes.  Match those ratings to other transistors and diodes.  What will be the operational voltage, power dissipation, etc?

Comment: Your first sentences should be explaining what you are trying to achieve because your question is unconvincing that you even know what those parts actually do. Do you know that a TIP121 is a Darlington? Or why you might want to use one of those instead of a single BJT? Explain where you are going with all this.

Comment: @jonk. You are right, I don't know why I'd want to use a tip121 over a single bjt.

This is my first project, and a friend told me if I could get all of the parts from the schematic I just updated the question with, he will show me how everything works and how to put it together. We are building a pulse width modulated power supply as a beginner project.

Comment: @brhans Can you explain why it's a 1N4148? Why would the schematic have it as 2N4148?

Comment: Instead of a Darlington, choose an Nch power "Logic Level" MOSFET with R<=0.1 Ohm. Put a shunt R like 10k across gate and choose a gold plated or carbon switch rated for<2A, otherwise contact oxidation will make it fail.  consider this http://www.taydaelectronics.com/datasheets/A-068.pdf. cheap

Comment: 2N4148 is obviously a typo.

Comment: There are 2x 1N4148, so the designer's brain gets confused. [Here](http://www.yesyes.info/index.php/how-tos/modding-an-spc880-900-webcam-for-long-exposure/) is another case where it happened. **Please note there is a mistake in the circuit diagram. The diodes are 1N4148, not 2N4148!**

Comment: The application requirements are not critical. Try 1N916 for 1N4148, both are small switching diodes. Try TIP122 for TIP121, it is practically the same except for high voltage rating.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any two-terminal item (diode) may have a 1Nxxx part number, but only
three-terminal devices get 2Nxxx part numbers in the JEDEC part numbering
scheme.   So, the "2N4148" is an error, it should be "1N4148", which is
a common and widely distributed switching diode.   TIP121 is also
an easily available part, about $0.69 at DigiKey.com.    That
same supplier has 660 000 of the 1N4148 available.

taydaelectronics.com DOES have 1N4148 listed[1N4148](http://www.taydaelectronics.com/diodes/1n4148-switching-signal-diode.html)
and a similar part to TIP121 (80V, 5A) is its sister part TIP120 (60V, 5A) or
another sibling TIP122 (100V, 5A).  Both TIP120 and TIP122 are available at
taydaelectronics.com.
The data sheet for TIP120, 121, and 122 is available if you want to
examine the detailed characteristics [TIP120-TIP122](http://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/datasheet/f9/ed/f5/44/26/b9/43/a4/CD00000911.pdf/files/CD00000911.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.CD00000911.pdf)

Answer (score 2):

> a tip 121 transistor and a 2N4148 diode

That is probably a TIP 121 and a 1N4148.

> I'm using the site taydaelectronics.com

So don't do that.  The 1N4148 is a very common diode.  You'll probably find it anywhere once you spell it correctly.  The TIP121 transistor is a bit more unusual, but should be readily available out there.

However, you should stop to understand the circuit and what each part does.  Then you can replace with a variety of parts since you know which specs are important.

The TIP121 is apparently a NPN darlington power transistor from your schematic.  That's a rather lazy choice, and it probably gets rather warm due to its high on-voltage.  A better choice is a N channel FET.  It's not clear, but it seems you have a 12 V digital output to drive the FET with.  If so, just about any N channel FET that can handle a few amps can do this.  You don't even need particularly low R<sub>dson</sub>.  Just about anything reasonable will drop less voltage than the darlington.